# Compiling flink in intellij failed

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to compile flink with intellij idea in windows and have followed all instruction here "https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/internals/ide_setup.html". But when building the project, I'm faced this error:

> java: package org.apache.flink.runtime.testingUtils does not exist

Comment: What build tool do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-test-utils -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-test-utils</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And then running "mvn clean install" in the terminal.